# Channel Entries pulled through to a site footer

Tags: channel-entries, templates, channel

The footer of my site needs to pull through the 6 most recent Case Studies. Here is the code, embedded in a template file for the footer of the site:

```
<li><strong>Case Studies</strong></li>
{exp:channel:entries channel="case_studies" limit="6"}
    <li><a href="{path="case_studies/case_study/{url_title}"}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Nice and simple, right?

This works perfectly on my homepage and under *some* URLs, but not all of them. For example, when I visit http://example.com/about/latest_news it will appear, as will http://example.com/press_articles/ - but http://example.com/services doesn't.

Is there anything obvious setting or reason for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, add `dynamic="no"` parameter to the `channel:entries` tag :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, I'm a bit of a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

This is easy: You need `dynamic="off"` on your `exp:channel:entries` tag.

EE automatically filters entries based on the URL, expecting that to contain entry IDs or URL Titles.

Comment: The other answer says `dynamic="no"` rather than off, which seems to work, but thanks for answering promptly.

Comment: Edit: Interestly, both `off` and `no` work the same...

Comment: Yeah, `off` used to be the value set in EE1.x, which carried over but is not documented.